# Powershell: Convert combobox.SelectedItem to time value to use at trigger for task scheduler

Tags: powershell

My question is how to convert a hour and minute chosen from a combobox to a time value that i can enter in my script for creating a tasks scheduler. I have method to pick the date through a monthcalendar, the only problem is the hour and minutes

```
write-host 'datum:   ' $dateTimePickerDatum.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString()
         write-host 'Hour:  ' $DropDownUur.SelectedItem.ToString()
         write-host 'Min:  ' $DropDownMin.SelectedItem

$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'c:\Users\plc\Desktop\script.bat'
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once $dateTimePickerDatum.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString() -At ($DropDownUur.SelectedItem.ToString()):($DropDownMin.SelectedItem.ToString())
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Bestand verplaatser" -Description "Het verplaatsen van bestand op gewenste tijdstip"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is an example that `$DropDownUur.SelectedItem.ToString()` and `$DropDownMin.SelectedItem` come across as? Are the hours digits? ie "04" Is it 24 hour format? ie "14"

You need to get it into the [System.DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) or just `[datetime]`format that the `-At` parameter takes.
Examples:

- "4:45"    = Today at 4:45 AM
- "4:45 pm" = Today at 4:45 PM
- "16:45"   = Today at 4:45 PM

Based upon the info I have, it will probably depend on how the Hour format is given.
The value following `-at` could work as `($DropDownUur.SelectedItem.ToString()+":"+$DropDownMin.SelectedItem.ToString())`guessing that both are digits. If you need to AM/PM if the Hour is 12 hour formatted, then you'll just need to add that to the string concat. `($DropDownUur.SelectedItem.ToString()+":"+$DropDownMin.SelectedItem.ToString()+" PM")`

Whole line:

```
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once $dateTimePickerDatum.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString() -At ($DropDownUur.SelectedItem.ToString()+":"+$DropDownMin.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

---

## Update

Also, I should have reorganized the date too. The date and time need to be after the -At switch. You're only using the -Once and -At switch here. Look at the docs for [New-ScheduledTaskTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=win10-ps) to see where things need to go. The date needs to be after the -At switch  like the time like so:

### Corrected:

```
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At ($dateTimePickerDatum.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString() + " " + $DropDownUur.SelectedItem.ToString()+":"+$DropDownMin.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

The effective string being made now is "11/02/18 4:45" which is in [datetime] format/structure to be read in by -At

Comment: Thank you so much it works, but now I have this problem "New-ScheduledTaskTrigger : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '11/02/2018'." It says that the datetimepickerdatum isn't a good argument.

Comment: See the answer edit, I should have caught that when I first looked at it. The date need so be after the -At switch.